# Is it possible to create a d3/svg circular canvas/container?

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to implement a circular canvas in d3.  I've tried editing this example of a rectangular canvas...

http://jsfiddle.net/k92end80/1/

But whenever I add an svg:circle it simply blocks any nodes behind it - does anyone know if this is even possible in d3/svg?

I was naively thinking I could just replace the below attributes with a  cx, cy, r attribute...

```
var container = d3.select("body")
                    .append("svg")
                      .attr("id", "svgcontainer")
                      .attr("width", 300) //replace with a cx
                      .attr("height", 300) //replace with a cy
//add a r attr
                      .style("background-color", "#aaaaee")
                      .call(zoom)
                    .append("g");
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: While not technicallly possible, consider using a svg `clipPath` (containing a `circle`) on a `g` element of the `svg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SVG 1.1 spec [tells us](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#Introduction):

> The canvas is infinite for each dimension of the space, but rendering occurs relative to a finite **rectangular** region of the canvas. This finite **rectangular** region is called the SVG viewport.

Taking that for granted neither d3 nor any other framework will be able to establish a canvas or viewport of any other shape.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback altocumulus and Josh.  Both very helpful, and Josh - the clipPath idea worked perfectly!!